# Ruby iteration error

Tags: ruby, arrays, iterator

When attempting to use iteration methods, I keep getting errors. This is an `initialize` method that creates a randomly sized array populated with random integers. Any help is appreciated.

```
 def initialize
   i = 0
   @random_size = rand(3-12)
   @new_arr = Array.new(@random_size)
   loop do
     @new_arr[i] = rand(1..50)
     break if i >= @random_size
     i += 1
   end
 end
```

---

**Edit**
The original question looked as below. Notice the `rand(3-12)`.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby (and any language that has some functional capabilities, for that matter) you don't usually write explicit indexes, that's too imperative (and verbose). A functional approach would look something like this:

```
def initialize
  @random_size = rand(3..12)
  @new_arr = @random_size.times.map { rand(1..50) }
end
```

Comment: *Not bad*, but blocks are a big thing to explain for those new to ruby.

Comment: Plasmarob: Anyone intending to learn Ruby should learn blocks, otherwise why bother? there are hundreds of tutorials and books out there, it's not that hard.

Comment: Fair. But at least call it one so they can look it up.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback.  My original question was edited and it looks like whoever edited it made some errors and cut out some info.  the rand(3-12) is actually a range: rand(3..12) as it is showing in my editor.  I am used to Java and am learning Ruby.  I was basically trying to mimic a for loop as you would in Java for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) etc.

Comment: I am the one who edited, and I didn't touch anything around `(3-12)`. It is the electr0hed's own mistake (if it were a mistake). **Hey electr0hed, Don't attribute your mistake to other people. Don't tell a lie.** The truth can be unveiled by looking at the edit history.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you man...I just copied this over from my editor which is showing rand(3..12).  Perhaps internet gremlins did it.

Comment: This was the kind of simplicity I was looking for. I kept attempting to use .each method and a value in a pipe as my book was describing. Will keep at it.  Thanks!